# weapon is supposed to flip after higher than 90 degress / lower than -90 degrees so it isnt upside down (unity2d)

Tags: unity-game-engine

The weapon flips if the angle is above 90 degrees like intended but doesnt flip if the angle is bellow -90 degrees. For some reason it does flip on the Y axis if the angle is 0 or 180 degrees.

```
if (Weapon.transform.eulerAngles.z < 90 && Weapon.transform.eulerAngles.z > -90)
{
    Weapon.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipY = false;
}
else
{
    Weapon.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipY = true;
}
```

[visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXdOR.png)

the weapon follows my mouse with this code:

```
Vector2 mouseScreenPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

Vector2 direction = (mouseScreenPosition - (Vector2)transform.position).normalized;

transform.right = direction;
```

i dont have any issues with the weapon pointing towards my mouse.

I already tried it with different angles but only the positive one flipped the weapon and 0 degrees. I appreciate every answer. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you try debugging without the if-else? Just to see the result of the angles in Unity, then adjust according to that?

Comment: Yes I did but it still flipped after 0 degrees for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with this:

```
if ((Weapon.transform.eulerAngles.z < 90 && Weapon.transform.eulerAngles.z >= 0) || (Weapon.transform.eulerAngles.z > 270 && Weapon.transform.eulerAngles.z <= 360))
```